# Self closed tags get opened in XMLTransform

Tags: xml, oracle, xslt, plsql, xmltype

I am using XSL Transform in PL/SQL oracle to transform one XML document into another. At the end I apply GetClobVal on XMLType object to return the results, but all the tags that were self closed (`<some_tag />`) now are opened (`<some_tag></some_tag>`).

The quesstion is what should I do in order to keep these tags as they were originally?

Comment: Maybe this is something dependent on Oracle versions. have a look at [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24486716/oracle-plsql-xmltype-transform-vs-xmltransform)

Comment: Does your original document have a mix of open/self-closed empty tags, and if so do you want to keep them all exactly as they were? Or do you want them [all to be self-closed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44440017/266304)?

Comment: Nothing should care; a self-closed tag and a tag with no content at all are semantically identical. Is this purely an aesthetic concern, or are you using a tool that needs them self-closing?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the XML output method and not HTML?